# SQL Server Count Across Cryptocurrency Tables

Tags: sql-server, pivot, union

In my database, I have about 15 tables named after cryptocurrency types. Here are examples of how the tables are organized. Each table is organized in the exact same way:

Table: Litecoin

```
ID      Date        State
-------------------------
1     2016-01-01      CO
2     2016-01-02      CO
3     2016-01-03     NULL
4     2016-01-04      FL
.
.
.
```

Table: Etherum

```
ID      Date        State
-------------------------
1     2016-01-01     NULL
2     2016-01-02      AK
3     2016-01-03     NULL
4     2016-01-04      FL
.
.
.
```

The structure is the same for the rest of my tables: Bitcoin, Dogecoin, Monero, etc. The tables have values for the entire year of 2016.

The result I have been trying to obtain is a query that shows a column with all the tables (each cryptocurrency), and the total number of occurrences for each state for the entire year. Ideally, the table would't show all 50 US states, but only the states that have occurrences. Below is an example of what it should look like:

```
Cryptocurrency   AK     CO     FL   ....
----------------------------------------
Litecoin        NULL    2      1    ....
Etherum          1     NULL    1    ....
.
.
.
```

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**:

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT   name as 'Cryptocurrency',[ID], State
FROM     Litecoin, sys.Tables
WHERE    isnumeric (name) <> 1
AND      State IS NOT NULL
AND      State <> '' 

UNION

SELECT   name as 'Cryptocurrency', [ID], State
FROM     Etherum, sys.Tables
WHERE    isnumeric (name) <> 1
AND      State IS NOT NULL
AND      State <> ''
```

Comment: Look up pivoting in SQL Server.

Comment: Just curious, but any specific reason you used different tables and not just have a column that identifies the type?

Comment: @musefan I used different table because each table (currency) has many other columns with different data and information, but those are irrelevant in this question. I have only listed the columns that are relevant.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Use PIVOT and UNION ALL

Comment: I have tried Union using sys.Tables, but it is quite complex since the tables don't have columns for each state